# Close existing instance when invoked from another app, Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

If my application is already opened and its getting invoked from another app, the existing instance of the application is present in the background. I want the application to be loaded inside the invoking application.  Unlike UPI payment applications, the existing background instance is not getting closed while invoking my app from another application.

```
    Invoking Application:
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.domain.myapp.entrypoint");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//tried 
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

My app manifest file:

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
        <activity
            android:name=".ReceiverActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="com.domain.myapp.entrypoint" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My app Cass file file:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(view);
                    //display home page details
                }
            }       
            
            public class ReceiverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(view);
                    //display details
                }
            }
```

What are the changes required, for opening up the existing background instance (if present) or starting a instance by killing the existing one.